# Gap is existing when customize the navigationbar with imageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, customization

Im using the following codes to customize the navigationbar with an UIView. But why there is a gap in the left size of the navigationbar? ps. the gradient image is test.png.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// show image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"test.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);

// label
UILabel *tmpTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 100, 44)];
tmpTitleLabel.text = @"title";
tmpTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
tmpTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tmpTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CGRect applicationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
[newView addSubview:imageView];
[newView addSubview:tmpTitleLabel];
self.navigationItem.titleView = newView;
}
```

**Edit 1**

Here is my test code and screen shot

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    

[super viewDidLoad];

UIView * viewGreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIView * viewRed = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

[viewGreen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[viewRed setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = viewRed;

[self.view addSubview:viewGreen];
}
```

Comment: @Abizern Just CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44), which is the frame of the navigationbar

Comment: @Abizern plz check the update of my question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved by the following code

```
[self.navigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

your code is work fine.just check the image and transparency.

To add the line at last  and check again

```
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```